# Using a custom hook in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to use a custom Axios hook to fetch some data but I get an error that says 'invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.' I know this sounds obvious but to a neewb this doesn't make that much sense.

Here is the hook:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default useApi = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async () => {
    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();
    setLoading(true);

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, { cancelToken: source.token });
      setData(response.data);
      setLoading(false);
    } catch (error) {
      if (axios.isCancel(error)) {
        // don't update state in case component is dismounting
        console.log("cancelled");
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
        setError(error);
      }
    }

    return () => {
      source.cancel();
    };
  };

  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```

I want to be able to use data, error, loading and request just like returned so I tried to use destructuring.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import useApi from "../hooks/http-hook";
const { request, data, error, loading } = useApi();


const SomeComponent = (props) => {

    useEffect(() => {
      const getUsers = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await request("http://localhost:8000/api/users");
          console.log(res);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };
      getUsers();
    }, [request]);
}

export default SomeComponent;
```

Comment: Give this a read https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your hook inside a component.

I see you are trying to call it just behind the import, and I suppose that is outside any kind of component. Try something like

```
import useApi from "../hooks/http-hook";

const YourComponent = () => {
    const { request, data, error, loading } = useApi();
    console.log(request, data, error, loading);
    return <Stuff/>
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have updated my question. I am not getting errors anymore but the console log outputs nothing even though I know I have data.

Comment: You are not getting the "url" param in anywhere. Maybe that could be the problem. Try to set const request = async (url) => {...}

Comment: Thanks, I tried that. Now in console I just get `[Function anonymous]`

Comment: Because the only return of the res function is an anonymous function "() => {source.cancel()}". Try to set the console.log just behind "setData(response.data);" to see your response